# Unity AR UI not showing up

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, augmented-reality

I have created a simple Unity AR Foundation app which places objects on a plane whenever the screen is touched. I would like to add some UI so the user can press a button rather than anywhere on the screen.

I have followed several different tutorials which seem to be doing mostly the same thing. I right-click the Hierarchy -> UI -> Button. I have scaled it so it should fit my mobile screen and anchored it to the center so it should be easy enough to find.

These are the canvas settings:

[image: Canvas settings]

Might the UI somehow be hidden behind the camera feed from the AR Session Origin -> AR Camera? Am I missing any steps to anchor the UI to the screen?

As you can probably tell, I am very new to Unity but I feel like I have followed the tutorials for creating a UI, but it simply won't show. If you need more information, please just ask and I will provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was compiling the wrong scene. I had two very similar scenes, so when I compiled I didn't realize there were no changes and that I was inspecting the entirely wrong scene.

Once I changed to the correct scene the setup above worked as expected.

Comment: Can i see your Hierarchy, I am having the same problem

Comment: Sorry, this project is long gone. However, the fix for me was to just find the correct scene and changing it. I can't help you more than that I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but sounds like you might need to have that Canvas Scalar to scale with the screen size. Change the UI scale mode to Scale with Screen Size.